# How to make event happen every 8 frames and last two frames (processing)?

Tags: processing

I have an event happening every 8 frames, using :

```
if (frameCount % 8 ==1){}
```

I cannot use :

```
if (frameCount % 8 < 1){}
```

because it would trigger the event for two frames, but I need the event to start when the modulo is equal to 1.

Basically I would like the event to be triggered when the modulo is equal to 1 AND 2, but I don't know how to do that. Can I specify a range in there ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the event to be triggered when the modulo is equal to 1 AND 2

No, an operation cannot have 2 results at once. You want to trigger the event, if `frameCount` is divisible by 1 **or** 2.

You have to use the `||`-operator ([logical OR](https://processing.org/reference/logicalOR.html)):

```java
if (frameCount % 8 == 1 || frameCount % 8 == 2) {
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had to go to on a 12 hrs shift. I'm not just impolite.